# On behalf of flow returns AADSTS50013 Assertion failed signature validation. Reason - The key was not found

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a Web API that needs to make calls to Microsoft Graph API on behalf of the user.  I'm using the OBO flow as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

To get the access token, I'm posting to

```
POST - https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
&client_id=<my-client-id>
&client_secret=<my-client-secret>
&assertion=<user's access token>
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/files.readwrite.all
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

The call fails with the following message:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found.]\r\nTrace ID: fb813f8e-ce15-4d09-bbae-9db5e5195a00\r\nCorrelation ID: ecb4e087-5506-4224-8f11-72fbf574beac\r\nTimestamp: 2020-10-22 02:18:57Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50013
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-10-22 02:18:57Z",
    "trace_id": "fb813f8e-ce15-4d09-bbae-9db5e5195a00",
    "correlation_id": "ecb4e087-5506-4224-8f11-72fbf574beac",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50013"
}
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

---

In response to @Chauncy Zhou,

I have an Angular app with:

"@azure/msal-angular": "^1.0.0",
"msal": "1.3.3"

In app.module, MSAL is configured something like:

```
    MsalModule.forRoot(  
    {  
    auth: {  
      clientId: environment.msClientId,      // app1-client-id  
      authority: environment.msAuthorithy,   // https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>  
      redirectUri: environment.msRedirectUri // https://localhost:4200/callback  
    },  
    cache: {  
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',  
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false  
    },  
  },  
  {  
    consentScopes: ['user.read', 'openid'],  
    protectedResourceMap: [  
      ['https://app-2', ['api://app-2-id/scope-name']],  
    ]  
  }  
)
```

In a test component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private msal: MsalService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.msal.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: ['api://app-2/scope-name'] }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Take the access token from console, and do a POST for OBO in postman.

Answer (score 2):

The error is `&assertion`.

You need to create two application,one is client application(test_1) and the other is web api application(test_2).

In the test_2 application,you need to expose an api.
[image]

And in the test_1 application,you need to give test_1 permission to access test_2.

[image]

The testing session.
First, use the ROPC grant flow to request access token for test_ 2 application

***ropc grant flow***

Note that the scope here is `api://{test_2 application id}/.default`.
[image]

Second,use OBO flow to request access token for microsoft graph api endpoint.

***on-behalf-of flow***
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.

I've set up a second application for the backend as you've described.

I don't think I can use ROPC since we have MFA set up.  But I have setup our Angular app with MSAL, and I have the accessToken for the backend.  I've checked the aud in the jwt and it corresponds to the backend app id.

Using this access token in the OBO post (and using the client_id and client_secret of app2), I still get the same response.

Comment: @5am Could you tell me how you got the access token to test?

Comment: I've updated the post to explain how I got the test token.  Thanks

Comment: I have configured the same way but getting error, could you please help.

{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS500131: Assertion audience does not match the Client app presenting the assertion. The audience in the assertion was 'api://c83c1c89-****' and the expected audience is '9f87e119-****' or one of the Application Uris of this application with App ID '9f87e119-****'(Frontend)."
    "error_codes": [
        500131
    ]
}