# Acquire Azure on-behalf-of access token in react next-app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, azure-active-directory, .net-6.0, next-auth

I'm encountering an issue with the "on behalf of" (OBO) authentication flow in my application. My infrastructure consists of the following components:

- A Next.js React app that utilizes the next-auth package for authentication.
- An API built with .NET 6.
- An Application Registration configured in the Azure portal.

I've implemented the standard `AzureADProvider` in my `api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` file. I've parameterized it with the client ID, client secret, and tenant ID from my application registration. Everything is functioning smoothly and I'm able to obtain a token from Azure. However, this token is intended for the Microsoft Graph resource, making it unsuitable for authenticating requests to my .NET 6 API.

To manage with this I would like to use the on-behalf-of flow to acquire an appropriate token for my API resource. Below is the next-auth JWT callback code:

```
const authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}`;
const config = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID as string,
    authority,
    clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    knownAuthorities: [authority],
  },
};

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);
const acquireOnBehalfOfAccessToken = async (assertion: string) =>
  await cca
    .acquireTokenOnBehalfOf({
      oboAssertion: assertion,
      scopes: [process.env.API_SCOPE as string],
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  ...
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      if (account && account.access_token && account.expires_at) {
        if (Date.now() < account.expires_at * 1000) {
          token.apiTokenDetails = await acquireOnBehalfOfAccessToken(
            account.access_token as string
          );
          return token;
        }
      }

      return token;
    },
  },
};
```

Unfortunately, I'm encountering an error:

> AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key
> was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'xxxx'

Surprisingly, I'm able to obtain my API token using a refresh token through the following method:

```
const generateApiAccessToken = async (refreshToken: string) =>
  await cca
    .acquireTokenByRefreshToken({
      scopes: [process.env.API_SCOPE as string],
      refreshToken,
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

How is possible, that I'm able to retrieve an access token using the refresh token method, yet I'm encountering difficulties with the on-behalf-of flow. The OBO flow seems like a more elegant approach for implementing authentication in both my React and .NET applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error may occur if you pass **wrong assertion** generated
> with scopes other than exposed API, to get access token in
> **on-behalf of** flow.

I have one application named `Web API` where I exposed **API scopes** as below:

[image]

Now I registered one client application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow with `API scope` via Postman:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <OBO_app_ID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: api://xxxxxxxxxxx/custom.scope
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can **decode** the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) to check **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims:

[image]

Now, pass above access token as **`assertion`** value in on-behalf of flow with **Microsoft Graph** scope. I generated access token using **on-behalf of flow** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <API_app_ID>
client_secret: <API_app_secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: <paste_token_from_above_request>
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I decoded this access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and got **audience** of Microsoft Graph with **User.Read** in `scp` claim.

[image]

When I used this token to call Microsoft graph, I got **response** successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, you need to first generate access token from **middle-tier API** with exposed API scope and use it as **`assertion`** for the OBO call to acquire token for Microsoft Graph.

**References:**

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret)

[azure active directory - On behalf of flow returns AADSTS50013 - Stack Overflow by **Chauncy Zhou**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474484/on-behalf-of-flow-returns-aadsts50013-assertion-failed-signature-validation-rea)