# Graph API: Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature failed., Thumbprint of key used by client: xxxx

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, azure, asp.net-core

I have an Angular application and I was able to generate the token for it using this example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa This works on the client side and I can generate the token. Now I want to send this token to my Web API and do call some graph APIs. This is my code to do that:

```
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
var tenantId = "xxxx";
var clientId = "xxxx";
var clientSecret = "xxxx";
var token = "token_obtained_from_angular_app";
var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, token);
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token2 = onBehalfOfCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, new CancellationToken()).Result.Token;
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
var user = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
```

But I keep getting this error:

'AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature failed., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'xxxx', Found key 'Start=02/08/2024 17:02:53, End=02/08/2029 17:02:53', Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'. Review the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments to determine the corresponding service endpoint and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to build a query request URL, such as 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000']. Trace ID: xxxx Correlation ID: xxxx Timestamp: 2024-03-18 11:00:00Z'

There is just one application which is created as Single Page Application (SPA):

[image: SPA on azure]

PS: Using same token if I call the Me API in Postman it works fine and I can get the profile but using GraphClient I am unable to. Basically all I want to do is get user profile from my token that was generate in the Angular application.

What am I missing?

Comment: While using on behalf flow, token_obtained_from_angular_app should have API as `aud` not Microsoft Graph. You will get that error if you are using token with MS Graph `aud` in on behalf of flow. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77000068/acquire-azure-on-behalf-of-access-token-in-react-next-app/77002285#77002285

Comment: @Sridevi thank you I followed that example of yours added in API permissions etc but still it did not work. You are using direct POSTMAN calls. Could you let me know what do I need to do in GraphClient class and how can I set aud in GraphClient? Been trying since 3 days but not working :(

Comment: @Sridevi do you mean in Angular app I should change the scope of API?

Comment: Yes, Change the scope to `api://client_id/.default` if you exposed any API and generate the token with that scope.

Comment: @Sridevi I configured in my Angular application to use scope scopes: 'api://web_apis_clientid/.default' now when I try to login the Angular is not generating any token. It gives error:  `ERROR ServerError: invalid_request: AADSTS50194: Application 'webapiclientid'(Web API) is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'.`

Comment: Could you include what value you are passing for `authority` parameter?

Comment: @Sridevi dear Sridevi bother not you have fixed my issue!! I set my web API to have multi tenant and now it works absolutely fine :)

Comment: Glad to know your issue is fixed, I'll post the same as answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257212/discussion-between-sridevi-and-k-v-sharma).

Comment: I feel familiar about `var token2` QAQ. Here we have a react client app and a web API project. The token we generated in the react app can help us access security resources, if the security resource is MS Graph API, then we should set the scope for Graph API, if it's our own custom API, then the scope should also match the custom API. Exposing custom API permission in AAD helps us secure our own web api. You are having a secured api, so the scope you used in react app should be what Sridevi said. Then you can use the code you shared to generate another access token for Graph API.

Comment: Hi @KVSharma please consider accepting the answer by clicking the ✅ beside it and upvote if it's helpful for you in any way

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred as you are using **Microsoft Graph** token as assertion in on-behalf of flow.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I tried to get on-behalf of token with assertion as Microsoft Graph scope:

[image]

> To resolve the error, make sure to generate access with exposed **API scope** *(api://client_id/.default)* and use it as **`assertion`** value for the OBO call.

You can decode that assertion by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check whether **`aud`** & **`scp`** claims have API values or not like this:

[image]

When I replaced the token with assertion generated with exposed **API scope** *(api://client_id/.default)*, I got the **response** successfully with signed-in user details:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appID";
        var clientSecret = "secret";
        var token = "token_with_API_scope";

        var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, token);
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);

        // Get the token
        var tokenResult = await onBehalfOfCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, new CancellationToken());

        // Print the token to the console
        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {tokenResult.Token}");

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
        var user = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

        Console.WriteLine();

        // Print user information to the console
        Console.WriteLine($"User Id: {user.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"User Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you are passing `/common` endpoint as authority, make sure change applications to **multi-tenant** in your case.